# After Starting Openshot Video editor

Tags: apt, package-management, python, python3, video-editor

```
tapabrata@lappy : openshot-qt
Loaded modules from: /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/openshot_qt

(python3:2102986): Gtk-WARNING **: 09:34:30.010: Theme parsing error: gtk.css:2515:35: '-2px' is not a valid color name

(python3:2102986): Gtk-WARNING **: 09:34:30.011: Theme parsing error: gtk.css:2521:35: '-3px' is not a valid color name

(python3:2102986): Gtk-WARNING **: 09:34:30.017: Theme parsing error: gtk.css:4428:30: '-2px' is not a valid color name
INFO app: ------------------------------------------------
INFO app:             Thu Sep 30 09:34:30 2021            
INFO app:               Starting new session              
INFO app: ------------------------------------------------
INFO app:           OpenShot (version 2.6.0-dev)          
INFO app: ------------------------------------------------
INFO app: openshot-qt version: 2.6.0-dev
INFO app: libopenshot version: 0.2.6-dev
INFO app: platform: Linux-5.11.0-37-generic-x86_64-with-glibc2.29
INFO app: processor: x86_64
INFO app: machine: x86_64
INFO app: python version: 3.8.10
INFO app: qt5 version: 5.15.2
INFO app: pyqt5 version: 5.15.4
INFO project_data: Setting default profile to HD 720p 30 fps
INFO language: Qt Detected Languages: ['en-IN', 'en']
INFO language: LANG Environment Variable: en_IN
INFO language: LOCALE Environment Variable: 
INFO language: OpenShot Preference Language: Default
ZmqLogger::Connection - Error binding to tcp://*:5556. Switching to an available port.
ZmqLogger::Connection - Error binding to tcp://*:5556. Switching to an available port.
INFO app: Setting font to /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/openshot_qt/images/fonts/Ubuntu-R.ttf
INFO logger_libopenshot: Connecting to libopenshot with debug port: 5556
INFO app: Setting custom dark theme
ERROR webview: Import failure loading WebKit backend
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/openshot_qt/windows/views/webview.py", line 163, in <module>
    from .webview_backend.webengine import TimelineWebEngineView as WebViewClass
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/openshot_qt/windows/views/webview_backend/webengine.py", line 38, in <module>
    from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineView, QWebEnginePage
ImportError: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Network.so.5: undefined symbol: _ZN15QIPAddressUtils8toStringER7QStringPh, version Qt_5

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/openshot_qt/windows/views/webview.py", line 167, in <module>
    from .webview_backend.webkit import TimelineWebKitView as WebViewClass
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/openshot_qt/windows/views/webview_backend/webkit.py", line 36, in <module>
    from PyQt5.QtWebKitWidgets import QWebView, QWebPage
ImportError: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Network.so.5: undefined symbol: _ZN15QIPAddressUtils8toStringER7QStringPh, version Qt_5
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/openshot_qt/windows/views/webview.py", line 163, in <module>
    from .webview_backend.webengine import TimelineWebEngineView as WebViewClass
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/openshot_qt/windows/views/webview_backend/webengine.py", line 38, in <module>
    from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineView, QWebEnginePage
ImportError: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Network.so.5: undefined symbol: _ZN15QIPAddressUtils8toStringER7QStringPh, version Qt_5

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/openshot-qt", line 11, in <module>
    load_entry_point('openshot-qt==2.6.0.dev0', 'gui_scripts', 'openshot-qt')()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/openshot_qt/launch.py", line 198, in main
    app.gui()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/openshot_qt/classes/app.py", line 263, in gui
    from windows.main_window import MainWindow
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/openshot_qt/windows/main_window.py", line 76, in <module>
    from windows.views.webview import TimelineWebView
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/openshot_qt/windows/views/webview.py", line 173, in <module>
    raise RuntimeError(
RuntimeError: Need PyQt5.QtWebEngine (or PyQt5.QtWebView on Win32)
INFO app:             OpenShot's session ended            
INFO app:             Thu Sep 30 09:34:31 2021            
INFO app: ================================================
```

This happens on 20.04 LTS.

Comment: What is your Ubuntu version? How OpenShot was installed?

Comment: Ubuntu 20.4 LTS

Comment: How OpenShot was installed? Add output of `apt-cache policy $(dpkg -S /usr/bin/openshot-qt)` .

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce the issue by adding [official PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Eopenshot.developers/+archive/ubuntu/ppa?field.series_filter=focal) to my fresh Ubuntu MATE 20.04.3 LTS system. I did the following:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:openshot.developers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install openshot-qt
```

So you have to check your Qt installation. I would recommend to reinstall Qt Network library with non-standard *_ZN15QIPAddressUtils8toStringER7QStringPh* symbol. Use command below:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall libqt5network5
```

and retry launching Openshot.